# tkinter file I/O breaks pythonw.exe drag and drop

Tags: python, tkinter, pythonw

Whenever I add file reading to a python tkinter gui like the code below, the program won't execute when I drag and drop the .py file into python.exe or pythonw.exe. I'm in Windows XP, using Python 3.2.

```
from tkinter import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    f = open('hello.txt', 'r')
    t = f.read()
    f.close()
    w = Label(root, text=t)
    w.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

I found that it will work if I set pythonw.exe as the default program for .py files then double click the file, or call it in cmd, but I really need to execute it with drag and drop. Is this a known bug? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `__name__` in the drag-and-drop case?

Comment: I saved only that code as gui.py, then dropped gui.py into pythonw.exe, so I think it should be __main__. But since the program doesn't run I can't output it to say, a print statement, so I don't know for sure. Is there another way to find out? Still new to python.